# How to update a value stored in an Object on "Update" button click - Android?

Tags: java, android

**I have the following class for an android application.**

```
public class AccountVO
{

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public AccountVO(String tempID, String tempUserName, String tempPassword, String tempEmail, String tempFirstName, String tempLastName)
    {
        this.id = tempID;
        this.username = tempUserName;
        this.password = tempPassword;
        this.email = tempEmail;
        this.firstName = tempFirstName;
        this.lastName = tempLastName;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

**I create the following objects in an activity.**

```
AccountVO userAccount = new AccountVO("1", "scott", "password", "scott@mail.com", "Scott", "James");
AccountVO userAccount2 = new AccountVO("2", "john", "password", "jsmith@mail.com", "John", "Smith");
```

**I have another activity where I retrieve the values from the objects which I created above and display them in EditText fields. Suppose I change the data in the fields and click on the "Update" Button, can anyone please tell as to how to update the values in my old AccountVO object? For Example: If I change the email via the edittitext field in "userAccount" AccountVO object (to say scott@abc.com), How to update that value in the same object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a setter for each of the fields you have a getter for, like so:

```
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Then, call the setter in the Update function:

```
public void Update() { 
    userAccount.setLastName(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: if we store AccountVO class instances in `HashMap<Integer,AccountVO>`  then we easy update or replace changes objects in next class